# Using Phonegap Build: Inappbrowser stops working after loading iframe in the main page

Tags: jquery, iframe, cordova, inappbrowser

I am writing an app using Phonegap 3.3.0 with Phonegap build. On my app, I have a button that the user can click on the load external page using iframe. I also have another button that the user can click on to load external page using inappbrowser. The problem is that inappbrowser often stops working after loading iframe in the main page of the app. What's really weird is sometimes it stops working even after I load the iframe multiple times and sometimes it continues working.

I know you might be wondering why I don't use inappbrowser to load all external pages. But I can't really pass the session data to the inappbrowser.

Has anyone encountered a problem with iframe and inappbrowser before? Is this a bug? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass anything to the page loaded by InAppBrowser

```
var inAppBrowser = window.open(yourURL);
inAppBrowser.addEventListener('loadstop', function () {
    inAppBrowser.executeScript(code: {
        //your code here with quotes
    }, function (yourCallBackVariable) {
        //callback code here
    });
});
```

follow what this guy is doing for more details : [http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova's-inappbrowser](http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova%27s-inappbrowser)

but I can't guarantee that your pages will work perfectly using inAppBrowser, some pages with twisted js may crash your inappbrowser, still better than using iframe...